# Why method with lifetime specified cannot be called twice?

Tags: rust

```
struct A<'a> {
    v: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> A<'a> {
    pub fn test(&'a mut self) {
        self.trivial();

        // Compiling error info:
        //       cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
        // first mutable borrow occurs here (last called self.trivial())
        self.trivial(); // Compiling error line.
    }

    // Trivial empty function.
    fn trivial(&'a mut self) {}
}
```

The compiling errors happen at the second called `self.trivial()` and compiler hints that it's the first calling `self.trivial` mutably borrow `*self`. And if the trivial function is defined by removing the lifetime 'a then everything is fine.

```
// ok then if no 'a specified.
fn trivial(&mut self) {}
```

My question is why does the lifetime `'a` influence the borrowing? I think function `trivial` has the parameter with type `&mut` which just accepts the argument and not borrow at all, how does the first calling borrow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *name* of the lifetime matters. When you give it `'a` as an explicit lifetime, you're saying the `&mut self` ref given to `trivial` must remain accessible for the lifetime of the struct itself. Which means it doesn't get "released" after the first call to `trivial`. If you change that to `trivial` having *its own* lifetime:

```
fn trivial<'b>(&'b mut self) {}
```

Now it'll work fine because the borrow only lasts as long as the function call. This is the same thing that's happening *implicitly* if you remove the lifetime annotation entirely.

Note that passing a `&mut self` (or any reference) into a function *is a borrow* -- "accepts an argument and not borrow at all" doesn't really make sense when that argument is a ref.